# Start a service from a referenced library in Android

Tags: android

I have an Android project that starts a Service. Then i turned that into an Android library and added it to another Android Project. 
Now i am trying to automatically start that service from my Main Android project but i am lost.
This is my code from manifest(i have added all my classed from library):

```
  <service
            android:name="com.test.mqttclientserver.MQTTService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="Service" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.test.mqttclientserver.MQTTService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name="com.test.mqttclientserver.MQTTClient"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.test.mqttclientserver.MQTTNotifier"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
```

In an Activity of the main project:

```
private boolean mBounded;
    private MQTTService mService;
    private MQTTConnectionStatus connectionStatus = MQTTConnectionStatus.INITIAL;  ..... public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public MQTTConnectionStatus getConnectionStatus() {
        return connectionStatus;
    }

    ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this, "Service is disconnected", 1000)
                    .show();
            mBounded = false;
            mService = null;
        }

        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this, "Service is connected", 1000).show();
            mBounded = true;
            LocalBinder mLocalBinder = (LocalBinder) service;
            mService = (MQTTService) mLocalBinder.getService();
        }
    };

    public void onStart(final Intent intent, final int startId) {
        System.out.println("onStart loading...");
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, MQTTService.class);
        bindService(mIntent, mConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        System.out.println("onStart ending...");
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mBounded) {
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mBounded = false;
        }
    }
```

Isn't this enough?  Just a hint would suffice. Thank you for your time.

Comment: The manifest referred to new application? or to the library?

Comment: the manifest is from the project, and references classes from the library added to the project

Comment: If the Service resides in an Android library project, then I am quite sure that your android:name elements in your Manifest's tags cannot all start with "com.test.mqttclientserver.".. I would expect something like "com.test.lib.MQTTService" and "com.test.mqttclientserver.MQTTClient" for the Service and first Activity respectively.

Comment: By the way: why do you have an intent-filter defined with your service? Seeing that you have android:exported="false" you might as well try to start it using an explicit intent (using ComponentName) instead of an implicit one (using Actions). Come to think of it.. that may also be a reason that you cannot start your service.. If you define an intent filter, I think you should at least add CATEGORY_DEFAULT, if you don't want to add a specific category.

Comment: i found on google that i should add permission for the library service: <uses-permission android:name="com.test.mqttclientserver.MQTTService" /> in the android project manifest. And left the service declaration like this:   <service
            android:name="com.test.mqttclientserver.MQTTService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:label="Service" >
        </service>. But no luck..

Comment: Post some code there you call start service